# Select all columns except null or NVL all null

Tags: sql, database, oracle, select, notnull

Is any way to select all columns in a record where fields are not null or NVL the null fields to ''?
Im working on ORACLE

Something like this

```
SELECT * IS NOT NULL
FROM table
WHERE id_table ='001'
```

or like this

```
SELECT NVL(*,'')
FROM table
WHERE id_table ='001'
```

Comment: No, that's not possible.

Comment: The system has to fetch all columns in order to recognize if it's content is empty/null. So what you can do is fetch all rows using the `*`, then using any programming language filter the result fetched

Comment: Non-trivial.  You'd first need to select all columns, and look for columns that were not null.  Then, build a new query dynamically with only those columns, and execute that.  It might be tricky to do in a way that was transaction safe as well.

Comment: Out of curiosity, could you explain what is the reason you're trying to do such thing ? Probably you have very specific needs. But as of myself, it sounds more like a normalization problem.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, Why not possible? Could you please elaborate, since your statement means it is impossible in Oracle. And that doesn't make sense to me, at all.

Comment: There is nothing to elaborate. What you want to do is simply not possible in SQL (neither in SQL nor in any other relational DBMS)

Comment: Usually, `SQL` has the capability to take care of lot of RDBMS operations. However, there are few things which could still be done in `PL/SQL`. So why to say something is impossible?

Comment: @LalitKumarB: of course you can do anything if you write a program for it - using PL/SQL is just that: writing a program. The example in the question implies that Paulo wants to do this with a single SQL statement.

Answer (score 2):

Just reverse the `NULL` logic in the demonstration about [Find all columns having at least a NULL value from all tables in the schema](http://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2014/09/25/find-all-columns-having-at-least-a-null-value-from-all-tables-in-the-schema/).

For example,

**`FIND_NULL_COL`** is a simple **user defined function**(UDF) which will return 1 for the column which has at least one **`NULL`** value :

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE
  2    FUNCTION FIND_NULL_COL(
  3        TABLE_NAME  VARCHAR2,
  4        COLUMN_NAME VARCHAR2)
  5      RETURN NUMBER
  6    IS
  7      cnt NUMBER;
  8    BEGIN
  9      CNT :=1;
 10      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select count(1) from '
 11                        ||TABLE_NAME||' where ' ||COLUMN_NAME||' is not null
 12                        and deptno = 20' INTO cnt;
 13      RETURN
 14      CASE
 15      WHEN CNT=0 THEN
 16        1
 17      ELSE
 18        0
 19      END;
 20    END;
 21    /

Function created.
```

Call the function in **SQL** to get the NULL status of all the column of any table :

```
SQL>   SET pagesize 1000
SQL>   column owner format A10;
SQL>   column column_name format A20;
SQL>   COLUMN TABLE_NAME FORMAT A20;
SQL>   column n format A1;
SQL>   SELECT c.OWNER,
  2      c.TABLE_NAME,
  3      c.COLUMN_NAME,
  4      C.NULLABLE,
  5      FIND_NULL_COL(c.TABLE_NAME,c.COLUMN_NAME) null_status
  6    FROM all_tab_columns c
  7    WHERE C.OWNER    =USER
  8    AND c.TABLE_NAME = 'EMP'
  9    ORDER BY C.OWNER,
 10      C.TABLE_NAME,
 11      C.COLUMN_ID
 12  /

OWNER      TABLE_NAME           COLUMN_NAME          N NULL_STATUS
---------- -------------------- -------------------- - -----------
SCOTT      EMP                  EMPNO                N           0
SCOTT      EMP                  ENAME                Y           0
SCOTT      EMP                  JOB                  Y           0
SCOTT      EMP                  MGR                  Y           0
SCOTT      EMP                  HIREDATE             Y           0
SCOTT      EMP                  SAL                  Y           0
SCOTT      EMP                  COMM                 Y           1
SCOTT      EMP                  DEPTNO               Y           0

8 rows selected.

SQL>
```

So, `NULL_STATUS` "1" is the column which has NULL value(s).

Comment: Link only answers should be avoided.  Perhaps copy over the relevant content?

Comment: Sure, why not. Let me add the content here.

Comment: In my timezone, it is almost midnight. I would add the content ASAP once I reach my workplace. Hope that is not going to violate any of the rules.

Comment: Your call.  Just trying to save you from getting any downvotes.

Comment: No upvote is better than a downvote without any reason. I try my best to help, and never thought about accumulating votes and points. As of now, I provided a link(my own content behind it)  with a small explanation. Whenever I get back on my system, I will post the content too.