# How to put default values for every column in table?

Tags: sql, oracle

This syntax doesn't work:

```
select  nvl(student.*,0)
from student ;
```

How can I apply a NVL() function to every column in STUDENT table?

Comment: Can you specify your question please? You want to select empty values or insert?

Comment: like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26064254/select-all-columns-except-null-or-nvl-all-null) ?

Comment: Why would you put null values in all columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can't do that.  We need to type out all the columns and their individual NVL() functions.  I know that seems like a lot of effort but consider what would happen if any of your columns is a DATE or some other "exotic" datatype.

If you have a lot of columns and you really want to save effort you could generate the clauses from the data dictionary:

```
 select 'nvl('|| column_name || ', 0)' 
 from user_tab_columns
 where table_name = 'STUDENT'
 order by column_id;
```

Cut'n'paste the result set into an editor.

Once you start on this route it's easy to get more sophisticated:

```
 select case when column_id > 1 then ',' end ||
       'nvl('|| column_name || ',' ||
       case when data_type = 'DATE' then 'sysdate'
            when  data_type = 'VARCHAR2' then '''DEF''' 
            else '0' end ||
       ')' 
 from user_tab_columns
 where table_name = 'STUDENT'
 order by column_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably something like this (if you are on **11g**), if you intend to write a PL/SQL, or else just `dbms_output.put_line` the variable `l_query` to get your query and execute it-

This will give you your query with ALL columns using `NVL`-

```
SELECT 'SELECT '|| listagg ('nvl('||column_name, ',0),') 
                            WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY column_name) ||',0) FROM TABLE1' 
     FROM all_tab_columns
    WHERE table_name='TABLE1';
```

And this is an implementation inside PL/SQL-

```
DECLARE
  v_record  table1%rowtype;
BEGIN
   SELECT 'SELECT '|| listagg ('nvl('||column_name, ',0),') 
                              WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY column_name) ||',0) FROM TABLE1' 
     INTO l_query
     FROM all_tab_columns
    WHERE table_name='TABLE1';

  l_query := l_query ||'  WHERE rownum<=1000'; --add where clause if you want to

  OPEN tab_cursor FOR l_query;
  LOOP
    FETCH tab_cursor INTO v_record;
    EXIT WHEN tab_cursor%NOTFOUND;
  END LOOP;

  --Do something with v_record
END;
/
```