# How to apply NVL function to every column in redshift query

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I want to apply a NVL function to every column in my query:

I.E I want to something like:

```
select nvl(student.*,'')
from student ;
```

Put another way, I would like this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33141933/how-to-put-default-values-for-every-column-in-table) answered but instead of Oracle SQL, use Redshift SQL

Comment: Always better to select each column from the table and then apply `nvl` or `coalesce`.

Comment: @zealous do you mean apply nvl to each column?

Comment: do you need all the columns?

Comment: Yes, I do need all the columns

Comment: There is no way you can do it in RedShift SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You have to go through one by one. If data type is `int` then replace it with `coalesce(col1, 0) as col1`

Example:

```
  select
    coalesce(col1, '') as col1,
    coalesce(col2, '') as col2,
    .
    .
    coalesce(colN, '') as colN
  from table
```